# Where to find online and easy reading material in traditional Chinese

Tags: traditional-characters, reading

I'm a native speaker who wants to learn to read chinese.  I know just enough that I can probably start reading very basic text and can look up each character as I go,  so I'm looking for easy beginner level short stories,  children's stories,  or any other beginning level text.  However, everything I find is simplified Chinese and I'm looking for traditional Chinese. Do you guys have any resources you can point me to that has text in traditional Chinese?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the Google Advanced Search.
key words: 兒童故事
language: Chinese (Traditional)
region: Taiwan

Some examples:

[兒童文化館](http://children.moc.gov.tw/animate_list?type=1)
[中文兒童故事](http://hi2100.com/Child/chd/chd01.html)
[兒童故事](http://www.play-kidsgames.com/flash/250/1.html)
[格林童話集](http://www.angelibrary.com/children/gt/)
[兒童睡前故事](http://storyfree.com/%E5%85%92%E7%AB%A5%E7%9D%A1%E5%89%8D%E6%95%85%E4%BA%8B)
[兒童故事](http://www.yfes.tn.edu.tw/yfesvi/story.htm)
[安安免費教學網－國小國語](http://ananedu.com/a/1/chinese1.htm)
[安安免費教學網－千篇文章共賞](http://ananedu.com/article/art-index.html)

Answer (score 1):

PangeaMT has launched a traditional Chinese translation panel which can be of use .
Go to https://pangeamt.com/translate/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with hinen and I also suggest you use this keyword "童話故事" to  find some related stories, and [this website](http://storyfree.com/%E5%85%92%E7%AB%A5%E7%9D%A1%E5%89%8D%E6%95%85%E4%BA%8B) also contains with some short stories you can read

Answer (score 0):

What about that you read the Traditional Chinese wikipedia (maybe print yourself to ease the reading process and take notes), and when you have difficulty guessing what a character is, just click the simplified version and read along; they have prepared auto transliteration feature. Before long you will have had basic familiarity with traditional Chinese characters, and you may read pretty much everything XD

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The reason I mentioned 'short texts'. And children stories is because I wanted something easy and fairly basic to start out.  But Wikipedia does sound like a good idea since it's more interesting than reading 3 little pigs

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have sufficient English-reading/writing skills. Therefore, you just might want to search for apps that teach English speaking people simplified Chinese.
Many offer the option to show traditional hanzi instead of simplied.

Short stories can be found here for example (Freemium-App): https://www.duchinese.net/